# Tag Sidebar Moving Up?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an article 'tag' sidebar which is positioned correctly on the Home page, but creeps up on all my other pages. Am using the Kaminari paginate plug-in. Its driving me nuts - how can I stop this from happening?

css

```
.sidebar {
position:absolute;
width: 150px;
float:right;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
margin: -1500px 0px 0px 700px;
}
```

_side.html.erb

```
 <div id="art">
 <%= link_to 'Post An Article', new_article_path %>
</div>

<div id="iphone">
<%= image_tag "iPhone.png" %>
</div>
<br />

<div id="soc-med">
<%= link_to image_tag("facebook.png"), "http://www.facebook.com/" %>
<%= link_to image_tag ("twitter.png"), "http://twitter.com/#!/" %>
</div>


<div id="tag_title">  
<h3>Article Tags</h3>
</div>

<div id= "tags" >
<% cache('all_tags') do %>   
<% for tag in Tag.find(:all, :order => 'name') %>


<ul style="list-style-type: none">
 <li>
<%= link_to "#{tag.name}", tag_path(tag) %>
</li>
</ul>

<% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: impossible to help without more code or a live link

Comment: it depends on the code between the home and the inner pages. Could you share both html codes?

Comment: @Ross @jackJoe - have added the code for this above. Can you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the 'top:130px;' attribute solved the issue:

```
.sidebar {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
position:absolute;
width: 150px;
float:right;
top: 130px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 700px;
}
```